# How to check the contents of the annotation @QueryParam of JAX-RS service

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I use `JAX-RS` to develop my rest service. I have a parameter in my url and I use `@QueryParam` like that:

```
@QueryParam(value="type") String type
```

I want to check the value `value="type"` of `@QueryParam` to display an error message if I write the parameter incorrectly. Exemple : `myURL?typekk=xml` instead of `myURL?type=xml`.

How can I check it ?

Comment: Just try to write your params in request correctly ))). Actual you can pass `HttpServletRequest` into your REST API method and check all params stored in request.

Comment: @eg04lt3r Thank you. It works well when using `HttpServletRequest`

Answer (score 0):

You should make the type parameter mandatory, typekk or anything similar will be a different parameter. You can use `javax.validation` annotations to enforce that the parameter is mandatory by annotating it with `@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`

```
@NotNull @QueryParam(value="type") String type
```

Comment: I resolved it by using `HttpServletRequest`. It doesn't work for me when using `@NotNull`